# Keyboard shortcut to toggle between "linear" and "professional" for a ms word 2019 equation

Tags: microsoft-word

In ms word 2019 I can toggle between linear and professional display of an equation by clicking on the arrow on the right of the equation and selecting then "linear" or "professional". However this is very annoying so I am looking for a keyboard shortcut to toggle between those two states. I should mention that I am using LaTeX syntax to edit the equation (maybe this does matter for the solution).

Answer (score 1):

*I've stumbled upon this question having a similar problem (and figured it out later), so it might help you or the others with my kind of problem.*
If you want to convert equation from standard state into **professional** for formatting purposes (e.g. numbering "**x=y+z#(3.15)**"), word does it automatically if you click **Enter** after you're done.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Word for Mac 16.77.1, you can customise keyboard shortcuts by going to `Tools` -> `Customise Keyboard...` .

In that window you can select the Category `All Commands` and search for commands `EquationLinearOne` and `EquationProfessionalOne` (or just type the beginning of these commands...).

Then you can specify a shortcut you like. I chose "cmd-shift-!" and "cmd-!" as they were unused and go with the default "ctrl-¨" on my keyboard layout.